# Callback-функция для libusb_set_log_cb

Tags: c++, libusb

Можно ли определить callback-функцию для libusb_set_log_cb внутри класса? Мне нужен доступ к полям класса, но если определять эту функцию внутри класса, то она не будет подходить из-за аргумента **this**

foo.h

```
class foo
{
    ...
private:
    int r;
    void handleLog(libusb_context *ctx, enum libusb_log_level level, const char* str);
};
```

foo.cpp

```
...

void foo::handleLog(libusb_context *ctx, enum libusb_log_level level, const char* str)
{
    ...
    std::cout << r << "\n";
}

...

libusb_set_log_cb(..., handleLog, ...); //
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно, но потом ее надо превратить в обычную функцию с помощью `bind`, указав при этом конкретный объект класса, для которого должна вызываться функция-член.

Comment: Минус не мой, но это сомнительно. `bind` возвращает функтор, как вы преобразуете его к указателю на функцию?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Запросто - обернуть его в функцию.

Comment: Положив в глобальную переменную? Тогда уж можно сделать глобальный объект/указатель на `foo`, и из функции вызывать `handleLog` сразу на нем.